# Pivot a spark dataframe and calculate sum of 2 rows above

Tags: pyspark

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|            name    |               1990|1991        |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|abc                 |100                |        300 |
|bbc                 |200                |        400 |
|cbc                 |300                |        500 |
|xyz                 |700                |        500 |
|xzz                 |200                |        500 |
```

Above is a dataframe in pyspark. I would like to convert this to a pivoted table and calculate a rolling summation. Is there a way to convert the columns to row on the name? Belo sis the expected result which is basically summation of previous 2 years. How can we accomplish this?

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|            year    |               abc |bbc         |
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+
|1990                 |100               |        300 |
|1991                 |100+200           |    400+300 |
```

Comment: your sample output looks incorrect? based on your input, `bbc 1990 = 200`, `bbc 1991 = 400`, then I thought this should be expected: `pivoted bbc 1990 = 200`, `pivoted bbc 1991 = 200+400 = 600`?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the task in two parts

- first create the pivot table and then
- use a window to calculate the sum

```python
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = ...

w=Window.orderBy("year").rowsBetween(-1,0)
df.withColumnRenamed("1990", "c1990").withColumnRenamed("1991", "c1991")\
    .selectExpr("name", "stack(2, '1990', c1990, '1991', c1991)") \
    .groupBy("col0") \
    .pivot("name", ["abc", "bbc"]) \
    .agg(F.first("col1")) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col0", "year") \
    .withColumn("abc_sum", F.sum("abc").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("bbc_sum", F.sum("bbc").over(w)) \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---+---+-------+-------+
|year|abc|bbc|abc_sum|bbc_sum|
+----+---+---+-------+-------+
|1990|100|200|    100|    200|
|1991|300|400|    400|    600|
+----+---+---+-------+-------+
```

*Edit*: using all values from the `name` column:

```python
df2=df.withColumnRenamed("1990", "c1990").withColumnRenamed("1991", "c1991")\
    .selectExpr("name", "stack(2, '1990', c1990, '1991', c1991)") \
    .groupBy("col0") \
    .pivot("name") \
    .agg(F.first("col1")) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col0", "year")

cols =[F.col("year")] + [F.sum(col).over(w).alias(col) for col in df2.columns[1:]]
df2.select(cols).show()
```

Comment: What would be the case when we dont know how many names we have in the name column? Can we dynamically choose the columns when we are not sure of how many of them are there? In the above code can we change this to reading the columns when size is unknown?

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz after creating the pivot table it is possible to get the resulting column names and then sum over all columns. I have added the code

Comment: Thanks. It does run, but, throws Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum.
: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Also, the sum in `bbc_sum` should be 100+200 for 1990 and for 1991 it should be 400+300. Looks like the result is wrong. It should do sum based on the previous column window range.

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz not sure if I understand your required logic... for bbc the value in the input data is 200 for 1990 and 400 for 1991. Where is the 100 coming from from?

Comment: I see that you are considering the rows, however, the summation should happen on the columns, say, abc_sum = 300 should be a result of previous 2 columns abc (100) + bcc (200)

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz if I look at the abc_sum: in which way is bbc (200) _before_ abc? How is this order defined?

Comment: Currently, the logic in place is comparing with the row above (or 2 rows above) and generating the sum. But, the ask was to compare 2 columns before (or the window functions should be based on the number of columns to check) and then add the columns together to generate the sum.